# How to pass data between preestablished windows in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Wizard class, which creates three pages in the form of QStackedWidget in its constructor. Each page is its own class.

In page one, I have a variety of forms and I've implemented the slot that assigns them when the next button is clicked. They're assigned to their respective variables in the Wizard class. My goal is to pass this information to the PageTwo class to do the appropriate computations. Any pointers on how to do this?

Wizard class

```
class Wizard : public QDialog
{
    Q_Object
public: 
    Wizard();
    QString nameInput;
    etc
}
```

constructor

```
Wizard::Wizard() : QDialog()
{
    pages = new QStackedWidget();
    pages->addWidget(pageOne = new PageOne(pages));
    pages->addWidget(pageTwo = new PageTwo(pages));
    connect(next, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(saveFormInfo()));
}
```

assignment function

```
void Wizard::saveFormInfo()
{
    nameInput = pageOne->nameEdit->text();
    etc
}
```

PageTwo class

```
class PageTwo : public QWidget
{
public:
    PageTwo(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void displayOutput(QHboxLayout *layout);
}
```

is this even the right way going about doing this? This is my first GUI project and I can't seem to figure out how to pass the variables in, I'm assuming because the page is created before the data is passed

Comment: If you're new to C++ the simplest way to pass information like this around is to use global variables. It's not ideal, but it's good to learn how to use them, and in doing so you may also learn why object oriented design shuns the use of them.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at the QWizard and QWizardPage classes. There is decent documentation and examples. Also, there's already a mechanism implemented to transfer data between pages

Comment: @RobbieE hey so I've looked into the mechanism for transferring data between pages which I'm assuming is using and registering fields. The functions associated with fields are protected members of QWizardPage. Because of this I'd would I have to rewrite and restructure everything?

Comment: Not too much. The general process involved is that each QWizardPage registeres a "field", which links a string field name to a control on the page. This can then be accessed from any other QWizardPage using the name of the field.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do it. Without changing too much your code, there is a suggestion below.

Wizard class

```
class Wizard : public QDialog
{
    Q_Object
public: 
    Wizard();
    QString nameInput;
    etc
}

Wizard::Wizard() : QDialog()
{
    pages = new QStackedWidget();
    pages->addWidget(pageOne = new PageOne(pages, this));
    pages->addWidget(pageTwo = new PageTwo(pages, this));
    connect(next, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(saveFormInfo()));
}

void Wizard::saveFormInfo()
{
    nameInput = pageOne->nameEdit->text();
    etc
}
```

On pagetwo.h

```
class Wizard;

class PageTwo : public QWidget
{
public:
    PageTwo(QWidget *parent = 0, Wizard * wizard);
    void displayOutput(QHboxLayout *layout);

private:
    Wizard * wizard;
}
```

On pagetwo.cpp

```
#include <wizard.h>

PageTwo::PageTwo(QWidget * parent, Wizard * w) :
    QWidget(parent), wizard(w)
{
}
```

Then you can use `this->wizard->nameInput` to get the value you want on PageTwo